# How to place these code into a Sub function and call it later when I use vbs?

Tags: vbscript

I'm a beginner of vbs, the Code A is written using vbs, it works well.

I find there are many repeated code in Code A, how to optimize the vbs code ?

**Code A**

```
Call Send_HTTP_RequestA()
Call Send_HTTP_RequestB()


        Sub Send_HTTP_RequestA()

                'Force the script to finish on an error.
                On Error Resume Next

                'Declare variables
                Dim objRequest
                Dim URL

                Set objRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

                'Put together the URL link appending the Variables.
                URL = "http://www.a.com/Task.aspx"

                'Open the HTTP request and pass the URL to the objRequest object
                objRequest.open "POST", URL , false

                'Send the HTML Request
                objRequest.Send

                'Set the object to nothing
                Set objRequest = Nothing

        End Sub
    


       Sub Send_HTTP_RequestB()

                'Force the script to finish on an error.
                On Error Resume Next

                'Declare variables
                Dim objRequest
                Dim URL

                Set objRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

                'Put together the URL link appending the Variables.
                URL = "http://www.b.com/task.aspx?From=VPSScedule&ForceRun=True"

                'Open the HTTP request and pass the URL to the objRequest object
                objRequest.open "POST", URL , false

                'Send the HTML Request
                objRequest.Send

                'Set the object to nothing
                Set objRequest = Nothing

        End Sub
```

**Added Content**

Thank you all! Is Code B correct?

**Code B**

```
Send_HTTP_Request  "http://www.1.com/Task.aspx"
Send_HTTP_Request  "http://www.2.com/task.aspx?From=VPSScedule&ForceRun=True"   
    
        Sub Send_HTTP_Request(URL)            
                On Error Resume Next
             
                Dim objRequest             
                Set objRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            
                objRequest.open "POST", URL , false
             
                objRequest.Send               
                Set objRequest = Nothing
        End Sub
```

Comment: A simple refactor would be to pass the url through as a method argument that way you only need one procedure, something like `Call Send_HTTP_Request(url)` where `url` is a string variable containing the url address. That way you can drop the `Dim URL` and `URL = ` in the method and the method signature becomes `Sub Send_HTTP_Request(url)`.

Comment: There is also a couple of misconceptions in the script, for example the use of `On Error Resume Next` without catching the error using `Err.Number` is dangerous as the code skips the line that errors and continues, it does not as the code comment says - "Force the script to finish on an error".

Comment: Thanks! Could you write a full code? I'm a beginner of VBS .

Comment: Never too late to learn - [Official VBScript Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/t0aew7h6(v=vs.84)). There's also a variety of VBScript resources on [so] as it's a 20+ year old language a lot of this has been covered many times.

Comment: Here's another [good resource](https://www.vbsedit.com/html/dd5dc02a-71e4-412b-8b30-9cc2d3d5e6fb.asp).

Comment: @LesFerch you realise that's just a copy of the old VBScript CHM files as HTML (still got the old script56.chm)? The software though is very useful.

Comment: @user692942 IMO, the online version is more convenient. I use Google to search it by adding "vbsedit" to the search term. Works great for me. YMMV.

Comment: @LesFerch cool tip, it frustrates me that Microsoft in their infinite wisdom decided to hide the official documentation from search engines.

Comment: Thank you all, is the Code B in my added content in the question correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your "Code B" will work, but, as noted in the comments, you shouldn't have an open ended `On Error Resume Next`. Add `On Error Goto 0` at the end of the code that you want error-suppressed. In between, report `Err.Number`. For example:

```
'Run using CScript ScriptName.vbs to get console output
Const Silent = False
Set oHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

Sub Post(URL)
  On Error Resume Next
  oHTTP.Open "POST",URL,False
  oHTTP.Send
  If Not Silent Then WScript.Echo VBCRLF & URL & VBCRLF & Err.Number
  On Error Goto 0
End Sub

Post "http://www.1.com/Task.aspx"
Post "http://www.2.com/task.aspx?From=VPSScedule&ForceRun=True"
```

Comment: Wouldn’t rely on OERN instead it should be checking for a successful response. Usually use `Call oHTTP.Send()` then use `If Left(oHTTP.Status, 1) = 2 Then` to check for a 200 range response status code. Would also pass the method as an argument so the function is more generic and support more than just `POST`.

Comment: I would also include the `Err.Number` check before the echo, in case there is no error: `If Not Silent And Err.Number <> 0`. But yes, after checking for a possible error beyond your control, like the `Send`, you should turn off error handling.